# How can I install MONDIAL on top of SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I tried the Oracle installation script [found here](https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/), but this requires the definition of an object type. SQL server doesn't support such object types .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GeoCoord AS OBJECT
(Latitude NUMBER,
Longitude NUMBER);
```

Comment: do you want create an object in sql server so do you required syntax to create

Comment: Why are you trying to create your own type instead of using the spatial feaures of SQL Server? Why not use a [geography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography) ?

Comment: SQL Server's spatial features are available in all editions, [even Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-supported-features-for-sql-server-2016#a-nameslsa-spatial-and-location-services), unlike Oracle which considered it an Enterprise feature, at least back in 9i

Comment: I need to use this type in another table.CREATE TABLE Mountain
(Name VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT MountainKey PRIMARY KEY,
 Mountains VARCHAR(50),
 Elevation int,
 Type VARCHAR(10),
 Coordinates GeoCoord CONSTRAINT MountainCoord
     CHECK ((Coordinates.Latitude >= -90) AND 
            (Coordinates.Latitude <= 90) AND
            (Coordinates.Longitude > -180) AND
            (Coordinates.Longitude <= 180)));

Comment: the database that I'm trying to use is in link https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/#SQL. but in oracle I need to use it in SQL-SERVER

Comment: You *don't* need this type as SQL Server already has spatial features. That's just a `geometry` type

Comment: The link you posted has nothing to do with this question. These are instructions for installing a different application on top of Oracle, Postgrest etc. You can't use scripts made for one database to run on another without modifications. That's why there are different scripts for Oracle and Postgres

Comment: so what do you recommend , how can solve the problem

Comment: Find the *correct* script, or someone who ported the script. The reason the Oracle script doesn't use spatial types is that these are expensive. I bet the Postgres script uses spatial types.

Comment: [Bob Beachemin](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/mondial-database-for-sql-server-2008/) posted a script for SQL Server 2008 back in 2007.

Comment: Thank you all , Problem Solved